# How to describe the chosen time period in a scientific paper?

Tags: phrase-usage

Example:

I want to say that the well abstracted groundwater in the period, let's say, 2010 - 2020.

Should I say "...in the years 2010-2020..."? Or "...during 2010-2020..."?

Another Example:

I want to say the analysis was conducted for the dataset consisting of observations from 1950-2020.

Should I say "...the study used the data for the years..." or rather "the data from 1950 - 2020 was used..." ?

Another Example:

I want to say that mean water level during 1990-2010 equalled X.

Should I say "For the years ... mean water level equalled..." or maybe "In the years...." ?

edit: or maybe "Between 1990 and 2010...." / "From 1990 to 2010..."

Thanks!

Comment: All those versions would be acceptable; or _between [the years] 2010 and 2020_

Comment: I think you may mean that the well *extracted* water, or that the well was a source of water, but *abstracted* is definitely not the right word to use here.

Comment: [Abstract](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abstract) can mean "to remove or separate someone or something from a place or context", but *the well abstracted groundwater* might be clearer as "the groundwater abstracted by wells" to disambiguate 'well *noun*' from 'well *adverb*'.

Comment: @stangdon Groundwater abstraction is a normal term in hydrogeology, https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/groundwater-abstraction

Comment: @crtnnn  Thanks for clarifying that!  If it's a "term of art" in the field, then it's absolutely correct.

Comment: I would use words rather than hyphens: The "annual data from 2010 through 2020". Data "to 2020" can be interpreted to mean ending on Dec. 31, 2019.  If there's ambiguity, explain. Scientific papers do not have the imperative of brevity and conciseness that magazine articles and speeches do.

Comment: Even if "abstraction" is an established term in the field, the word "well" is still ambiguous.

Comment: Not sure whether this applies in such a technical context, but there **might** be a subtle difference in meaning between *the data for the years [timespan]* and *the data from [timespan]*. "The data for the years [timespan]" definitely means "data which pertains to the specified timespan," while at least to me, "the data from [timespan]" could imply either the same as the preceding, **or** that the data itself was collected during that timespan.  Or, the difference could be moot if the data both *pertains to* and *was collected in* the same interval.

Comment: "the difference could be moot if the data both pertains to and was collected in the same interval. "-> Yes that's my case.

"I would use words rather than hyphens: The "annual data from 2010 through 2020". Data "to 2020" can be interpreted to mean ending on Dec. 31, 2019." -> Wow, well I didn't think about it this way. I think I will go with "through" after your insight.